# Laravel Vue Routing

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I would like to hava all tr as a router link in my table, but when I add this before tr, then every css from table disappear and my View looks bad. Is a possibility to do this better?

```
<table v-if="seenOrders" id="ordersTable" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Numer zamówienia</th>
            <th>Imię</th>
            <th>Telefon</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Data zamówienia</th>
        </tr>

        <router-link to="/orderDetail" class="order-row" >
        <tr v-for="order in orders" v-on:click="details(order.id)">
            <td>{{order.number}}</td>
            <td>{{order.client_name}}</td>
            <td>{{order.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{order.email}}</td>
            <td>{{order.actual_status}}</td>
            <td>{{order.order_date}}</td>
        </tr>
        </router-link>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<router-limk>` will by default render as a `<a>` element. If you want to change how the `<router-link>` should render use the `tag` prop (in your case `<tr>`)

```
<router-link to="/orderDetail" tag="tr" class="order-row" >
```

So your code should be

```
<table v-if="seenOrders" id="ordersTable" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Numer zamówienia</th>
        <th>Imię</th>
        <th>Telefon</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Data zamówienia</th>
    </tr>

    <router-link to="/orderDetail" v-for="order in orders" tag="tr" class="order-row" >
        <td>{{order.number}}</td>
        <td>{{order.client_name}}</td>
        <td>{{order.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{order.email}}</td>
        <td>{{order.actual_status}}</td>
        <td>{{order.order_date}}</td>
    </router-link>
</table>
```

See tag section of [`<router-link>`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html)